# Is it possible to call the same function with a Scale and a checkbutton in tkinter using Python 3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, tkinter, scale

I have a scale that calls a function to get the scale number. I want to have a lot of more things in that function, and I would like them to happen not only if I move the scale, but also If I select the checkbutton. The problem is the Scale sends a variable to the function (position of the scale) and the checkbutton doesn't, so If I use the command of the checkbutton to call the same function I receive an error. Anybody knows if is possible to call the same function with a Scale and a Checkbutton?

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

def get_scale(scale_value):
    print(scale_test.get())

scale_test = Scale(root, from_=0, to = 10, command = get_scale)
button_test = Checkbutton(root)

scale_test.pack()
button_test.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Provide a default value: `def get_scale(scale_value=1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Mike67, it works:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

def get_scale(scale_value = 1):
    print(scale_test.get())

scale_test = Scale(root, from_=0, to = 10, command = get_scale)
button_test = Checkbutton(root,command = get_scale)

scale_test.pack()
button_test.pack()

root.mainloop()
```